# How to determine weight differences between steaks delivered

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have had 16 steaks delivered all of varying weights, despite stipulating an average weight +/- 20 grams.  How can I easily calculate the difference between the lowest, highest and average weights using excel?  I know the average (simple formula) but how can I take this further?  The weights are:

```
290
284
239
340
365
372
329
239
372
329
239
303
263
297
259
251
AVE = 298
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the MIN and MAX functions?  They give you the other two points.  It isn't clear if you're asking about something beyond that.

Comment: Thanks. I had not used MIN / MAX before. This has now given me the results I was looking for. So simple yet so powerful.

Comment: Consider posting your own answer with the solution you came up with.  That will make this thread more useful to others with a similar problem.